# symfony form label attribute 'for' not changing according to form_widget 'id' change while passing through template

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

i am rendering a form containing form fields in symfony
in my template i am doing rendering the form part by part 
like this
`{{- form_label(form.category,'Categoryname',{ 'label_attr' : {'class': 'control-label','for':'Cname'}}) -}}
 {{- form_widget(form.category,{ 'attr': {'class': 'form-control col-md-10','max-length':55},'label': 'Category name','required':true,'id':'Cname' }) -}}`

but 'id' of the form field change as 'Cname' but the for attribute in the label not change it show what is default by symfony
How can i change the "id" of the form field and "for" attribute of the corresponding label ?

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the *form_label*. For details, see [Making Application-wide Customization](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations). Original form template stored in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig. For example, you can change the part of block *form_label*

```
{% if not compound -%}
    {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
{%- endif -%}
```

to

```
{% if not compound -%}
    {% set label_attr = {'for': id}|merge(label_attr) %}
{%- endif -%}
```

And now custom parameter *for* in *label_attr* will overwrite the default widget *id*.